# How can I properly store email in Joomla column?

Tags: php, sql, email, joomla

I have created a form for my joomla 3 site that collects the visitor's email address.  After submission I am collecting the value like so:

```
$email = $input->post('email');
```

I am then inserting them in the database like so:

```
$values = ...$db->quote($email)...;
```

I have reviewed Joomla's coding guidelines here: http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines

I see that when an email is inserted in the database like I am showing in this question the `@` and `.` are being stripped from the value to help prevent sql injection.  I am sure that there is a simple Joomla workaround for inserting an email, but I am having trouble locating the syntax.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Joomla before, but after reading the documentation, I think you will have to specify a filter when retrieving the value that doesn't strip out characters. Perhaps:

```
$email = $input->post->get('email', 'default_value', 'RAW');
```

This would give you the input unfiltered, but of course you should be careful with that. Perhaps a different filter listed on the guidelines page would be more appropriate.

FYI I think the above line is long-hand for:

```
$email = $input->get('email', 'default_value', 'RAW');
```

Comment: wow!  that works great.  For someone who has never used joomla you sure did spot that fix fast.  Thanks so much :)